# Vcalendar shows a minute time difference in Outlook Desktop Application

Tags: php, outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

I'm trying to create vcalendar file using the PHP script. The vcalendar file get generated correctly and recognized by the Gmail and Outlook Web application but whenever I try to open the vcalendar file in outlook Desktop Application it adds one extra minute in the start and end date. I have check this file on different machines but the issue is still there. I have added the vcalendar code for reference.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:48a00c6d5deac25dd6e1307538f1a51a
DTSTAMP:20180824T112806Z
DTSTART:20180824T112812Z
DTEND:20180824T132812Z
ORGANIZER;CN=nameoforganizer:mailto:organizer@demo.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;
 CN=name;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:name@demo.com;
SUMMARY:summary goes here   
DESCRIPTION:blah blah
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Can you please help me to figure out what is wrong here!

Comment: In [Thunderbird Lightning](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) it displays "13:28 to 15:28" for me (I'm in UTC+2), without seconds. What do you mean with "one extra minute": "11:29:06" or "11:29"? Maybe some clients always round up.

Comment: That's weird.  Anyone else using outlook see same behaviour ? Google Calendar rounds down 11.28.  Even a 1/2 timezone difference shouldn't cause that.

Comment: @TobiasK. If I try to schedule meeting at 15:28:xx to 17:28:xx then the outlook desktop shows the date 15:29:xx to 17:29:xx and the strange thing is that the web application shows the correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution to this problem. Actually the problem is with the outlook the desktop app it rounds up the second according to value. Ex. if I have a time like 15:30:40 then outlook consider it as 15:31:00 and 15:30:25 to 15:30:00.

Removing the seconds from the time stamp resolved the problem.